# QTextStream unusable after reading into a char variable

Tags: c++, qt

So this is the client part of my assignment that I'm coding.

```
#include "coordinate.h"
#include "gpscoord.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    GPSCoord gps;
    int degrees, minutes, seconds;
    char cardinalDirection;

    cout << "\nPlease enter values for the latitude.." << endl;
    cout << "Degrees : " << flush;
    cin >> degrees;
    cout << "Minutes : " << flush;
    cin >> minutes;
    cout << "Seconds : " << flush;
    cin >> seconds;
    cout << "Cardinal Direction : " << flush;
    cin >> cardinalDirection;

    gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

    cout << "\nPlease enter values for the longitude.." << endl;
    cout << "Degrees : " << flush;
    cin >> degrees;
    cout << "Minutes : " << flush;
    cin >> minutes;
    cout << "Seconds : " << flush;
    cin >> seconds;
    cout << "Cardinal Direction : " << flush;
    cin >> cardinalDirection;

    gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

    cout << "\nGeographic Coordinates\t: " << gps.toString(false) << endl << "Decimal Coordinates\t: " << gps.toString(true) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first half works fine. But as soon as I enter the input for the first cardinalDirection, the program sets the coordinate but then just prints the rest of the output one after the other and doesn't want for any input. Here is the output.

```
Please enter values for the latitude..
Degrees : 25
Minutes : 46
Seconds : 3
Cardinal Direction : S

Please enter values for the longitude..
Degrees : Minutes : Seconds : Cardinal Direction : 
Geographic Coordinates  : 0ø, 0', 0", S ; 25ø, 46', 3", 

Decimal Coordinates : 0 ; 25.775
```

Is it something stupid that I'm missing? Can't imagine what would cause this.

Comment: What's the platform? I can't reproduce after removing the use of `gps`, on neither windows nor OS X, on both Qt 4 and 5. Please provide [a minimum, self-contained test case](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: I'm using OS X Mavericks, with Qt 4.8 as far as I know. Removing the line

gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

changes nothing except that the variables printed out at the end are still 0.

Comment: @nickoring Yeah, sorry, I thought it was `std::cin`!

Comment: In the end, it turns out that it's a bug in your code and a bug in Qt - both at once :) Your bug essentially exposes a Qt bug; in absence of your bug the Qt bug wouldn't manifest :) +1 for catching a Qt bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt has a bug [QTBUG-37394](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37394), and your code has a bug too :)

- Your bug: When reading single characters into either `char` or `QChar`, you will read whitespace that terminated any preceding input. You must use `ws(stream)` to get rid of existing whitespace in the stream.
- Qt bug: the character-reading operators wait for non-whitespace data even if there is already a whitespace character available in the input stream.

### Details

The reason it doesn't work is that what you consume as a character is the newline from the *previous* line.

1. After you enter, say, 20 arcseconds, the contents of the character buffer are:

   ```
   { '2', '0', '\n' }
   ```
2. After `cin >> arcseconds` runs, the character buffer is:

   ```
   { '\n' }
   ```
3. Then, `cin >> cardinalDirection` runs, and waits for new input since there's nothing interesting in the buffer (that's the Qt bug: it shouldn't wait). Suppose you enter `N`, the character buffer is now:

   ```
   { '\n', 'N', '\n' }
   ```

   Now, `operator>>(char&)` *correctly* retrieves the first character in the buffer, no matter what it is. Thus it retrieves `'\n'` and succeeds (that's your bug: you should get rid of the whitespace first). The character buffer now contains:

   ```
   { 'N', '\n' }
   ```
4. The problem is then that now you read the longitude. The buffer contains non-whitespace data, and the following executes *immediately*: `cin >> degrees`.

   As expected, reading an `N` into an integer fails, and no further output is processed.

   If you'd enter a digit, say `1`, it will succeed, and you will have the curious exchange when it asks for degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinal direction and then asks for minutes while skipping degrees.

The fix is to forcibly skip the whitespace in the the data. The documentation for `QTextStream::ws()` method has this telling sentence:

> This function is useful when reading a stream character by character.

```cpp
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

class GPSCoord {
   QString dir;
public:
   void setCoord(int, int, int, char d) { dir.append(d); }
   QString toString(bool) const { return dir; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    GPSCoord gps;
    int degrees, minutes, seconds;
    char cardinalDirection;

    cout << "\nPlease enter values for the latitude.." << endl;
    cout << "Degrees : " << flush;
    cin >> degrees;
    cout << "Minutes : " << flush;
    cin >> minutes;
    cout << "Seconds : " << flush;
    cin >> seconds;
    cout << "Cardinal Direction : " << flush;
    ws(cin) >> cardinalDirection;

    gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

    cout << "\nPlease enter values for the longitude.." << endl;
    cout << "Degrees : " << flush;
    cin >> degrees;
    cout << "Minutes : " << flush;
    cin >> minutes;
    cout << "Seconds : " << flush;
    cin >> seconds;
    cout << "Cardinal Direction : " << flush;
    ws(cin) >> cardinalDirection;

    gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

    cout << "\nGeographic Coordinates\t: " << gps.toString(false) << endl
         << "Decimal Coordinates\t: " << gps.toString(true) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're interested. The solution to the assignment was released today. In the solution, cardinalDirection was read in as a QString and then passed as a parameter using cardinalDirection.at(0).toAscii(). Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @nickorin The solution offered is slightly more correct, I merely attempted to make your code work with minimal changes :) Your code  fails if you enter anything more than a single character. A `QString`-consuming solution fails if you enter more than one word. The *only* correct thing to do is to use `cin.readline()` :)

Comment: This is true :) Although specifically for the assignment we were told to assume all input was valid and not to do error checking or validation. Is there some way I can contact you outside of StackOverflow?

Comment: @nickorin Look in my profile at the pane on the right.

Answer (score -1):

`cin` doesn't like your `char cardinalDirection`. It works for me when I change the declaration to `char cardinalDirection[2];`

**Edit:**
As Kuba Ober pointed out, this can lead to a buffer overflow situation. There's no real input validation or error handling in the existing code, but I should be more thorough in my own answers.

If you wish to restrict to a certain number of characters, you can do the following.

```
char cardinalDirection;

...

cout << "Seconds : " << flush;
cin >> seconds;

//read everything from the buffer to clear
//it out - there are still some newlines
//in the buffer from previous input
cin.readLine();

cout << "Cardinal Direction : " << flush;
//read one character from the input and convert it to a char
cardinalDirection = cin.readLine(1)[0].toAscii();

//in case the user entered more than 1 character, clear out the buffer again
//so that the next inputs will work correctly
cin.readLine();

...
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to compile with the change.. error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'char [1]'
        gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection);

Comment: @nickorin Sure, because you're supposed to fix it: `gps.setCoord(degrees, minutes, seconds, cardinalDirection[0]);`

Comment: If I change the parameters for the function my entire program goes haywire because of comparisons between int and char* >.<

Comment: @nickcorin What is the method signature of setCoord?

Comment: Reading into a fixed-size buffer is a wonderful source of buffer overflows. Bad advice :) My hope was that you'd see that merely enlarging a buffer is a never-ending story. You can imagine my next comment could have been: "OK, now let's pretend I will enter AB, and you overrun the buffer again."

Comment: Kuba, could we speak over email about something? The email of yours I tried didn't work. nickcorin@gmail.com